# PHP Function with MySQL Query output

Tags: php, mysql, function, output

```
// Sum of boys and girls for each school 

function bgTotSkl($bgTotSkl_SchoolName, $conn) {
    $bgTotSkl_Query = "SELECT SUM(result_studpoints) AS totalbg, stud_gender
    FROM result
    JOIN students ON result.stud_id WHERE result.stud_id = students.stud_id
    AND stud_school = '$bgTotSkl_SchoolName' 
    GROUP BY stud_gender";
    $mainQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $bgTotSkl_Query);
while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mainQuery)) {
echo bgTotSkl($bgTotSkl_SchoolName);
    }
}

echo bgTotSkl("CCA");
```

The code above is a function that contains a mysql query. The query is supposed to calculate the sum of the points for boys and girls gained by a specific school in my database. The query works fine, I have tested it.

Also the variable in my query represents school name so when I want to output the totals for a specific school 
e.g:

```
echo bgTotSkl("CCA");
```

The school CCA will be placed in the function and the query will grab the total points for boys and girls from the database for the specific school CCA.

The problem is I cannot get the function to output the results of the query and I do not know if my syntax is wrong (have I implemented the variable in the query correctly?) or the whole logic is wrong (Is the while loop completely wrong?) or both.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: **WARNING**: When using `mysqli` you should be using parameterized queries and [`bind_param`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php) to add user data to your query. **DO NOT** use string interpolation or concatenation to accomplish this because you will create severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/). **NEVER** put `$_POST` data directly into a query.

Comment: Notice: use PHP Database Objects PDO

Comment: Also call like `echo bgTotSkl("CCA",$conn);` `connection object is missing there`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two tings:-

**1.Inside `function`add this two line first:-**

```
if(isset($bgTotSkl_SchoolName)){
 $bgTotSkl_SchoolName = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$bgTotSkl_SchoolName);//It will prevent `SQL Injection`
}
```

**2.Call function like:-`echo bgTotSkl("CCA",$conn); connection object(second parameter) is missing there`**

**Now try like below:-**

```
function bgTotSkl($bgTotSkl_SchoolName, $conn) {
    $bgTotSkl_Query = "SELECT SUM(result_studpoints) AS totalbg, stud_gender
    FROM result
    JOIN students ON result.stud_id WHERE result.stud_id = students.stud_id
    AND stud_school = '$bgTotSkl_SchoolName' 
    GROUP BY stud_gender";
    $mainQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $bgTotSkl_Query);
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mainQuery)) {
        echo $data['stud_gender'].' has gained overall '.$data['totalbg'].'points';
    }
}

bgTotSkl("CCA",$conn);
```

**Or:-**

```
function bgTotSkl($bgTotSkl_SchoolName, $conn) {
$result = array();
    $bgTotSkl_Query = "SELECT SUM(result_studpoints) AS totalbg, stud_gender
    FROM result
    JOIN students ON result.stud_id WHERE result.stud_id = students.stud_id
    AND stud_school = '$bgTotSkl_SchoolName' 
    GROUP BY stud_gender";
    $mainQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $bgTotSkl_Query);
    while ($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($mainQuery)) {
        $result['stud_gender'] = $data['totalbg'];
    }
}
$college_name = 'CCA';
$data = bgTotSkl($college_name,$conn);

foreach($data as $key=>$value){
   echo $key.' of college '.$college_name.' has gained overall '.$value.'points';
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I have done this but it still does not output anything.

Comment: Do you think there could be a problem with my while loop in the function?

Comment: I cannot tell because i don't know what is this going to do:- `bgTotSkl($bgTotSkl_SchoolName);`

Comment: I think that line is the problem. I just want to output but I dont know how to output functions that contain mysql queries.

Comment: That line bgTotSkl($bgTotSkl_SchoolName); does nothing, I thought it would do something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple tutorial for mysqli prepared statements: http://markonphp.com/mysqli-select-prepared-statements/

Hope it helps.